# Primary Action Triggered post keyboardWillShowNotification

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I did some research but still can't find any answers. The scenario is simple:

I have a ViewController, called `MainVC`
I put 2 observers inside viewDidLoad

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

- I have a `UITextField`, with linked Primary Action Triggered to MainVC, called `doneAction`
- Everytime I press "Return" key, it posts `keyboardWillShowNotification`, althought there is not a single line of code inside `doneAction`

Is this some kind of bug or weird reaction of `UITextField`? Or a offical behavior?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: With "Return" key aciton/press, `keyboardWillHide` notification should trigger. Please cross check the other location where you might miss to deregister the observers.

Comment: @RJ168 I did check and no, there isn't unwanted observer. And "Return" key (with Primary action triggered linked) won't do anything if you don't `implement` endEditing or `resignFirstResponder`

Comment: I can't produce the same with Xcode 11.2.1 + Swift5, what is the configuration at your end?

Comment: Xcode 11.3, target iOS 11+, Swift 5. Nothing's special.